# Bluz framework enable errors

Tags: php, frameworks

How to enable errors in  [Bluz framework](https://github.com/bluzphp/framework) ? By default it doesn't show errors.

Comment: Have you enabled PHP errors?

Comment: yes i have enable PHP errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `BLUZ_DEBUG` cookie on page `/system/bookmarks`  or in `path_to_project/public/index.php` find

`$debugKey = getenv('BLUZ_DEBUG_KEY') ?: 'BLUZ_DEBUG';
if (isset($_COOKIE[$debugKey])) {
putenv('BLUZ_DEBUG=1');
}`

end replace to

`putenv('BLUZ_DEBUG=1');`

see https://github.com/bluzphp/skeleton/wiki/Module-System 
but Russian